# How to get a video height width excluding the background

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the video height and width excluding the background. If I do `document.querySelector('video').videoWidth`, I will get the width according to the video quality if I am not mistaken, and if I do `document.querySelector('video').offsetWidth` this will give me width with background. So how do I actually get the width that is covered by video?

Following image shows the width I am looking for:

[image]

```
document.querySelector('video').videoWidth gives 288
```

```
document.querySelector('video').offsetWidth gives 1920
```

```
needed width: 1129px
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this `document.querySelector('video').style.width`
which will give you the fill area or the box surrounding the hole video which in this case is equal to the video width